# How can I write (make directory, write file, ...) on a real sd card

Tags: android, android-external-storage, removable-storage

I want to create a folder and write a file in real external storage (real extern sd card).
I can write to the internal storage, the external storage, but not to the external sd card (I mean the external storage card you put into a cell phone for more space to store images, videos, ...).
The path of the external sd-card is: "/storage/1234-5678/" and it is on a samsung smartphone.
Reading from the external sd card works without problems.
I am testing with Android 8 (and later with higher versions).

I have searched through internet and try but not getting the result, I have added permissions in Android Manifest file as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

and an easy test is:

```
File directory = new File("/storage/1234-5678/new_folder/");
if (!directory.exists()) {
    boolean ok = directory.mkdirs();
}
```

The result to ok is always false, when I use the path to the external / removable sd card.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since providing a direct path might be a problem. So I would recommend using the Android file access mechanism.

**Mentioned here**->https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-select-location

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs().

You can write on that location of the removable micro sd card.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() returns the path to files folder inside Android/data/data/your_package/ on primary external storage, which is inbuilt storage.
This is access to internal storage, or see more at https://gist.github.com/granoeste/5574148 also to other storage, but not to external, removable SD card. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes. But i was not talking about getExternalFilesDir(). Please read better.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read correctly about getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs().
With getExternalFilesDirs() I get "/storage/1234-5678/Android/data/my_packagename/files/".
But I don't want create the folder
/storage/1234-5678/Android/data/my_packagename/files/new_folder, but /storage/1234-5678/new_folder (direct at root).
Do you know a solution?

Comment: You cannot do that with the classic file classes as since Android 4 Kitkat a removable micro sd card is read only except for that directory.

Comment: You have to use Storage Access Framework instead.

Comment: I'm not a pro, more of a good beginner. Do you know a good example for me?